# Low classification accuracy, what i should do?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, openml

i'm trying to make a classification about this dataset:

https://www.openml.org/d/1475

i'm using predominantly scikit learn and i tried to select features by their correlation coefficients:

```
#X is the training data
X1 = X.transpose()
cr = np.corrcoef(X1)
   count = 0
index = []
for i in range(n_features):
    for j in range(n_features):
        if ((cr[i, j] > 0.85 or cr[i, j]<-0.85)  and i != j and i < j):
            print(i, '-', j, 'valore:' + str(cr[i, j]))
            count = count + 1
            index.append(i)
```

or their VIF, with this function:

```
def VIF(dataset, n_feature):
    df = dataset.iloc[:, 0:51]
    df.dropna()
    df = df._get_numeric_data()  # This line will drop non-numeric cols
    df.head()

    # For each X, calculate VIF and save in dataframe
    vif = pd.DataFrame()
    vif["VIF Factor"] = [variance_inflation_factor(df.values, i) for i in range(df.shape[1])]
    indici = []
    for i in range(n_feature):
        indici.append('feature:' + str(i + 1))
    vif["features"] = indici
    return vif
```

then i trained and tested datas with svm (trying 'rbf','linear' and 'poly', with optimazed values of C), k-NN and MLPClassifier but the best result was an accuracy of near 57%. i also tried to test svm with the train data and also in that case i obtained a very low accuracy.this is the code about svm:

```
svm = SVC(kernel='rbf', decision_function_shape='ovr',C=1)

svm.fit(all_train_data, all_target)
ypred = svm.predict(all_train_data)

cf = confusion_matrix(all_target, ypred)
print(cf)
print(classification_report(all_target, ypred))
print('Accuracy on the test set is: ' + str(np.round(accuracy_score(all_target, ypred) * 100, 2)) + '%')
```

in the site below i found a lot of sperimental result about this dataset, and they obtained predictive accuracy near to mine. what can i do?

https://www.openml.org/t/9985

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Based on  the link you provided, you haven't done badly in building your classification model, so well done. In terms of improving your model so that you get closer to the higher scores shown on that page, you should try

- Replicating some of the models that did well, particularly random forest and gradient boosted trees
- Skipping your feature selection step - let your classification algorithm choose important features for you (choose one that will such as the two mentioned in the previous bullet) as correlation is not always a good indicator of whether a variable is important (the classic example is that in a classification of whether someone survives, the information about whether they had taken a certain antidote would be essential if they had also taken the related poison but irrelevant otherwise)

Comment: in term of computational cost of the algorithm, is it more important to reduce the number of features if the reduction doesn't influence (a lot) the accuracy? sorry for dumb question but i'm new in ML :)

Comment: That's not a dumb question! In general, the important thing is to make the model accurate. You will know by running the model whether it is fit for purpose in terms of computational cost and can then optimise if necessary. If you start with a computationally heavy model that works it is sometimes possible to reduce the complexity of the model, by changing its hyperparameters or reprocessing the input data, and retain much of the accuracy.